# Getting mod_wsgi(reviewboard) and mod_php(wordpress) working on same servername but different path

Tags: macos, wordpress, apache, mod-wsgi, mod-php

I'm trying to get my wordpress site as well as my reviewboard site working under the same domain name.

Ex:

```
www.mysite.com (this is where i host my wordpress site)
www.mysite.com/reviewboard (this is where I want to host my reviewboard site)
```

I can get one or the other to work depending on my httpd-vhosts.conf file.  However, I cannot get both to work(this is where I need your help!).

This is how I host my wordpress site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite"
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ErrorLog "/opt/local/apache2/logs/mysite.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/opt/local/apache2/logs/mysite.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This is how I host my reviewboard site(which then breaks my wordpress site):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs"

    # Error handlers
    ErrorDocument 500 /errordocs/500.html

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias "/reviewboard" "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/reviewboard.wsgi/reviewboard"

    <Directory "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs">
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Alias static media requests to filesystem
    Alias /reviewboard/media "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/media"
    Alias /reviewboard/static "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/static"
    Alias /reviewboard/errordocs "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/errordocs"
    Alias /reviewboard/favicon.ico "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/static/rb/images/favicon.png"
</VirtualHost>
```

So, now I want to be able to figure out how to combine these somehow so I can have reviewboard hosted at the path specified above without breaking my wordpress site. I tried using the Alias command as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553165/multiple-django-sites-with-apache-mod-wsgi
and here
https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines

However I can't get it to work.  Here's my WIP.  If you can be very specific as what I need to do in order to change this so it works that would be great since I'm new to this kind of stuff. Thanks!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite"


    # Error handlers
    #hmm not sure where to put this since my document root is different??????
    #ErrorDocument 500 /errordocs/500.html

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    Alias /reviewboard/ /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/

    <Directory "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs">
        Options ExecCGI
        SetHandler wsgi-script  
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Alias static media requests to filesystem
    # Since I added the alias command above these are complaining about 
    #overlapping an earlier alias when I restart my apache server????
    Alias /reviewboard/media "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/media"
    Alias /reviewboard/static "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/static"
    Alias /reviewboard/errordocs "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/errordocs"
    Alias /reviewboard/favicon.ico "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/static/rb/images/favicon.png"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of what djc wrote and some of my tinkering here's the working version so that:

```
www.mysite.com (wordpress site loads correctly)(mod_php)
www.mysite.com/reviewboard (reviewboard site loads correctly)(mod_wsgi)
```

*Important* make sure you clear your browser cache every time you restart your apache server as I kept falling into the trap of it showing incorrect data since I forgot to do that.

*Important2* Make sure the "/reviewboard" follows the "reviewboard.wsgi" to become "reviewboard.wsgi/reviewboard" otherwise it will not work and gives a 404 error!

Here's the working version:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite"
    ErrorLog "/opt/local/apache2/logs/mysite-error_log"
    CustomLog "/opt/local/apache2/logs/mysite-access_log" common

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias /reviewboard /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/reviewboard.wsgi/reviewboard
    <Directory /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard>
        Allow from all
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    # Alias static media requests to filesystem
    Alias /reviewboard/media "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/media"
    Alias /reviewboard/static "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/static"
    Alias /reviewboard/errordocs "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/errordocs"
    Alias /reviewboard/favicon.ico "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/static/rb/images/favicon.png"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same domain for both, you can't use different VirtualHost sections for both. So first off, you have to merge both configurations into a single VirtualHost section. I'd start with the WordPress config, then add a few bits for ReviewBoard:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite"
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ErrorLog "/opt/local/apache2/logs/mysite.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/opt/local/apache2/logs/mysite.com-access_log" common

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias /reviewboard /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/rb.wsgi
    <Directory /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /reviewboard/media "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/media"
    Alias /reviewboard/static "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/static"
    Alias /reviewboard/errordocs "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/errordocs"
    Alias /reviewboard/favicon.ico "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mysite/reviewboard/htdocs/static/rb/images/favicon.png"

</VirtualHost>
```

You need to create a WSGI script (but you should already have that). You might want to put it in a different path than what I put in the config here, so your permissions are more secure.

Comment: When I use the code you pasted it allows my wordpress site to be visible on the server root but my reviewboard site when I type in www.mysite.com/reviewboard gives the following error: Not Found, The requested URL /reviewboard was not found on this server. Even though it does exist in a folder called reviewboard in my root directory.

Comment: My path was wrong to my wsgi script and I've fixed that.  So, this is an improvement!  I am now able to see my site as well as the reviewboard site(as in the page loads the reviewboard art/look). However, it shows a 404 error with the reviewboard saying that "The page you were looking for does not exist".  Maybe it's because Document Root isn't at mysite/reviewboard?  Is there a way to fix this?