# How to deploy Django with mod_wsgi on Debian machine?

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have installed apache2, mod_wsgi on my Debian machine and added this on my `apache2.conf` file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /home/zurelsoft/Documents/workspace/genalytics/genalytics/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/zurelsoft/Documents/workspace/genalytics

<Directory /home/zurelsoft/Documents/workspace/genalytics/genalytics>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

My project name is `genalytics`. I am using Django 1.5. There's already wsgi.py available. What should I do run the django with mod_wsgi and where should I give the path of my static files. Thanks

**Edit**

I have this on my apache.conf file:

```
Listen 8000

Alias /static/ /home/zurelsoft/Documents/workspace/genalytics/fileupload/static

<Directory /home/zurelsoft/Documents/workspace/genalytics/fileupload/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /home/zurelsoft/Documents/workspace/genalytics/fileupload/static


<Directory /home/zurelsoft/Documents/workspace/genalytics/fileupload/static>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

But when I run try to start apache I get this error:

(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.

Comment: We don't know what your project looks like.

Comment: The Django documentation covers how to set things up. Am not sure why people want to keep referring to random blog sites for how to do it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you have set up everything correctly, you don't have much left to do.

In your application root, create a file named django.wsgi and write the following code.

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/path/to/your/app')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/path/to/your/app/.python-egg'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Now, add a virtual host in your apache configuration for serving static and other files and add the following lines:

```
   WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/your/app/django.wsgi

   <Directory /path/to/your/app>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   Alias /robots.txt /path/to/your/app/robots.txt
   Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/your/app/favicon.ico
   Alias /images /path/to/your/app/images
   Alias /static /path/to/your/app/static

   ErrorLog /path/to/your/app/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /path/to/your/app/access.log combined
```

Remember to restart apache.
You can check [this](https://library.linode.com/frameworks/django-apache-mod-wsgi/debian-5-lenny) and [this](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/jul/8/setting-django-and-mod_wsgi/) links for complete information. Also, if you need to know how to add virtual host, check [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) out.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I already have a file called wsgi.py provided by Django. Do I need to create another file called django.wsgi

Comment: I get this error:
[....] Starting web server: apache2(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: In the first case, i'm not sure, try both.
2nd case, some app has already taken that port 80. Change that number in your VirtualHost declaration.

Comment: Did that, didn't work. I have specified line listen 8000 but doesn't work.

Comment: this might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553165/multiple-django-sites-with-apache-mod-wsgi?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of howtos on the web, most of which work with current Django versions, but I was unhappy with their lack of conformance with Django's current docs and found the easiest path to follow these instructions:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

There it says: 'As of Django version 1.4, **startproject will have created wsgi.py** for you' - which looks like this:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

So now it's *wsgi.py* that connects to mod_wsgi, which you installed with aptitude, and *django.wsgi* is deprecated.

Now we want to honor the **debian method** of configuring apache sites, so instead of putting the following code into httpd.conf, as django-docs propose, we create a *dj-myapp* file in /etc/apache2/sites-available, activate it with *a2ensite dj-myapp* and disable default with *a2dissite default*.
The WSGI-directives are written before the virtualhost section:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
      <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
      </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is for apache 2.2x, for 2.4+ use *Require all granted* instead of *Allow from all*.

Finally configure the static file serving, as described in the django docs. The directives are also placed in *dj-myapp*. For the admin static files this line worked for me:

```
Alias /static/admin /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin
```

Comment: there is no mention of the website URL here, how does apache knows what website it is?

Comment: If you want apache to serve multiple sites on separate domains, you just add these kind of directives to the (or each) dj-myapp in the Virtualhost section:

'        ServerName www.supersite.de
        ServerAlias supersite.de  *.supersite.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/super/'

There is nothing specific with django, wsgi or python here.

Comment: - - - - - - - - -
( its stupid that I can not enter line breaks in comments :(

Comment: (it's also stupid of stackoverflow that I can edit comments only for 5 minutes :(

Answer (score 0):

create file called app.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available.The app.conf:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIPythonPath /home/brms/manage/web/brms
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=brms group=brms threads=4 \
   python-path=/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /home/brms/manage/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
                Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    Alias /meetingApp /var/www/meetingApp
</VirtualHost>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/brms/manage/wsgi.py
```

Enable this site：`sudo a2ensite app.conf`
Restart Apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`