# Xampp and apache

Tags: hosting

I am looking to go from 000webhost towards my own server. I saw many people use apache and I downloaded xampp to use apache. How can I configure it to where it can go from localhost to towards a public host? I needed to get some libraries for C++ and I am not too sure I can put it on a shared hosting service so I need my own server. How can I configure apache or xampp to go from localhost to a public host?

Comment: You'll need to open some ports on your router to your server and know your external IP address.

Comment: Is it free such as apache claims?

Comment: Be careful about 000webhost --> http://www.zdnet.com/article/000webhost-hacked-13-million-customers-exposed/

Comment: Is what free? Hosting a website on your own server? That would be up to your Internet Service Provider, not apache.

Comment: My internet sucks so I guess that is out

Comment: @Shondeslitch so that is why they have been locking my account with PHP files do they still check premium accounts?

Comment: @GoldDragon I don't know anything more :/

Comment: What exactly is your end goal here? Host a website or share files?

Comment: Well I wanted to host my own site because 000webhost said none of the hosting sites support C++

Comment: Im not sure if I can upload the C++ libraries either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple django sites with apache & mod\_wsgi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553165/multiple-django-sites-with-apache-mod-wsgi)

Comment: Its no duplicate -_- because 20 questions I searched through have no use to my needs. Do people get rewarded here for throwing assumtions and closing posts? If so maybe I should as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to host your C++ libraries in your own computer. However, hosting a website in own machine is never recommended because of following reasons.

1) You'll need high bandwidth and fast Internet connectivity 24x7 to ensure speedy availability to your site. Web Hosting providers have 1  Gbps connectivity which is impossible for local ISP to offer.

2) You will have to keep your computer up for 24/7. You would need static IP address to host your application or else you will need to use third party DNS services such as dyndns.

Most of web hosting providers setup their web servers to serve either PHP or ASP.net based websites so you would rarely find web host supporting C++.

The only option available to you is a Windows VPS. You can use Windows VPS according to your requirement either to upload and serve C++ libraries or to host websites.

Comment: Good answer not what I wanted to hear but at least I know now. I actually worked with my hosting service they give paid plans for VPS and we can install anything Linux based including support for C++ totally forgot about this question.