# Trouble trying to host 2 django webs on the same apache2 server

Tags: python, django, linux, apache

I have been pulling my hair out with this and I dont know what else I should do.
For context, I am trying to host 2 django websites on the same Apache2 server. I am able to setup 1 website with ease but whenever I try to add a second one everything breaks.
At the momento both webs are located in in **/home/my_usr** dir.
So we would have **/home/my_usr/web1** and **/home/my_usr/web2**.

My *web1-web2.conf* file looks like:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess web1 python-home=/home/my_usr/web1/env python-path=/home/my_usr/web1
WSGIProcessGroup web1

WSGIDaemonProcess web2 python-home=/home/my_usr/web2/env python-path=/home/my_usr/web2 
WSGIProcessGroup web2
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that the server uses to 
    # identify itself. This is used when creating redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the 
    # ServerName specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to match this virtual 
    # host. For the default virtual host (this file) this value is not decisive as it is used as a last 
    # resort host regardless. However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg. It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular modules, 
    # e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are enabled or disabled at a global level, 
    # it is possible to include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the following 
    # line enables the CGI configuration for this host only after it has been globally disabled with 
    # "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    Alias /web1/static /home/my_usr/web1/static 
    <Directory /home/my_usr/web1/static> 
        Require all granted
    </Directory> 
    
    Alias /media /home/my_usr/web1/media 

    <Directory /home/my_usr/web1/media> 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    <Directory /home/my_usr/web1/web1> 
        <Files wsgi.py> 
            Require all granted 
        </Files>
    </Directory> 
 
    WSGIScriptAlias /web1 /home/my_usr/web1/web1/wsgi.py

    Alias /web2/static/ /home/my_usr/web2/static 
    <Directory /home/my_usr/web2/static> 
        Require all granted
    </Directory> 
    
    Alias /media /home/my_usr/web2/media 

    <Directory /home/my_usr/web2/media> 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    <Directory /home/my_usr/web2//web> 
        <Files wsgi.py> 
            Require all granted 
        </Files>
    </Directory>  
    WSGIScriptAlias /web2 /home/my_usr/web2/web2/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

With this conf file, and right after I execute `sudo service apache2 restart`, if I go onto **host/web1** web1 works perfeclty fine but if I want to access to **host/web2** I get an error message and this error in the error.log file:

```
[Fri Jul 02 11:45:45.210666 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29254] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Debian) mod_wsgi/4.6.5 Python/3.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 02 11:45:45.210780 2021] [core:notice] [pid 29254] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.416556 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195] mod_wsgi (pid=29256): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/my_usr/web2/web2/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.416650 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195] mod_wsgi (pid=29256): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/my_usr/web2/web2/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417397 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417464 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "/home/my_usr/web2/web2/wsgi.py", line 24, in <module>
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417517 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417526 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "/home/my_usr/web2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417530 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417546 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "/home/my_usr/web2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417550 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417555 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "/home/my_usr/web2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417559 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]     self._setup(name)
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417564 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "/home/my_usr/web2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417567 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417572 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "/home/my_usr/web2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417575 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417580 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417583 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417588 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417593 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417598 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417603 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417608 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417612 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417617 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Fri Jul 02 11:46:13.417634 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 29256] [remote 192.168.20.32:25195] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web1'
```

Whereas, if I execute `sudo service apache2 restart` and directly go onto **host/web2** now web2 works perfectly fine but if after that I try to go onto **host/web1** it shows web2.

So  basically if I restart apache2 service then go to **host/web1** and after that **host/web2** I get a message error and the logs posted.

If I restart apache2 service then go to **host/web2** and after that **host/web1** I get web2 contents even though the url is **host/web2**

Any clue what could be going?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running the two servers on different ports?

Comment: @FloLie No, same port (80)

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553165/multiple-django-sites-with-apache-mod-wsgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I figured it out! Hope this helps someone in the future.
So my .conf file was all good from the headstart what was giving me trouble was the .settings files of my django projects.
Thanks to [this](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html) article I fixed it.

I had my settings files like this:
`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')`

And changed it to:
`os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'`